# How to find same elements of a list in 2d list python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have the following 2D list:

```
test_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['I', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'B'], ['J', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

I want to compare the 1st list elements of the 2D array `test_list[0]` with all other lists. If the elements `['A', 'B', 'C']` are present in all other lists then it should print any message such as "All elements are similar".

I have tried this piece of code but it is not working as I expected:

```
test_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['I', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'B'], ['J', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
  
for idx,ele in enumerate(p):
    result = set(test_list [0]).intersection(test_list [(idx + 1)  % len(temp_d)])
    
    print(result)
```

**Expected Output:**

The elements of the list ['A', 'B', 'C'] are present in all other lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `all(...)` function - or remove all elements from the bigger list from your smaller one converted to set. If the set.difference() is Falsy (i.e. all elements were removed) they were all contained in it:

```
test_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['I', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'B'], ['J', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'C']]

s = test_list[0]
for e in test_list[1:]:
    if all(v in e for v in s):
        print(e, "contains all elements of ", s)

s = set(s)
for e in test_list[1:]:
    # if all elements of s are in e the difference will be an empty set == Falsy
    if not s.difference(e):
        print(e, "contains all elements of ", s)
```

Output:

```
['I', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'B'] contains all elements of  ['A', 'B', 'C']
['J', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'C'] contains all elements of  ['A', 'B', 'C']

['I', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'B'] contains all elements of  {'A', 'B', 'C'}
['J', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'C'] contains all elements of  {'A', 'B', 'C'}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each letter in the first list see if they are in the second and third list and return the boolean.

Then see if the `set` of the new list equals `True`

```
test_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['I', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'B'], ['J', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'C']]

bool = ([x in test_list[1]+test_list[2] for x in test_list[0]])

if list(set(bool))[0] == True:
    print('All elements are similar')

>>> All elements are similar
```